# Select a range using Subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am Trying to solve the problem below using a subquery - but always get the result that it returns more than 1 value... Can someone help me?

I have three tables (a couple more actually, but don't think they are needed in this description) which simplified looks like this:

```
MARK                  STAFF_RESOURCE     PLACING
----                  --------------     -------
ACCOUNT_DAY           EMPLOYNO           RES_ID
MARK_TIME             RES_ID             PLAC_ID
MARK_TYPE
PLAC_ID
```

The MARK-table has data like this:

```
ACCOUNT_DAY  MARK_TIME                  MARK_TYPE   PLAC_ID
-----------------------------------------------------------
2015-02-05   2015-02-05 13:02:01.029    1           5
2015-02-05   2015-02-05 18:32:21:744    2           5
2015-02-06   2015-02-06 09:02:01.029    1           5
2015-02-06   2015-02-06 14:32:21:744    2           5
```

The result I would like if doing a range selection on ACCOUNT_DAY (for instance february), looks like - this joining the tables by the IDs:

```
EMPLOYNO   ACCOUNT_DAY   MARK_TIME (1)              MARK_TIME (2)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
03064      2015-02-05    2015-02-05 13:02:01.029    2015-02-05 18:32:21:744
03064      2015-02-06    2015-02-06 09:02:01.029    2015-02-06 14:32:21:744
```

Comment: where is the query ?

Comment: @AmeyaDeshpande Since the query I made didn't work at all as I wanted I was hoping that someone could give me a suggestion of how to build it. :)

Comment: Use CROSS APPLY.. But is there always exactly two rows in the Mark table for every account_day?

Comment: @dean There can be more than two rows in the Mark Table, but by linking it to another table I can sort the "wrong ones" out.
Never used CROSS APPLY. Will have a look at it! ty!

Comment: looks like join `MARK` with `PLACING` with `STAFF_RESOURCE`and pivot the result. you have to know how many marks you can have